# Is there a term denoting the index list of a multiply-inexed object, such as a tensor component?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, terminology, definition, tensors

Suppose we have a tensor expressed in component form as $T_{ij\dots{k}}$.

**Is there a name for the construct ${ij\dots{k}}$?**

I might call it a *multi-index*, but prefer not to invent newfangled words where there is an established vocabulary.

Comment: Multi-index already exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation but I'd call your thingy just an index.

Comment: I believe that is the same horse, flogged to death.

Comment: It seems that the word "multiindex"  is used only if some computations are done in the "index space", as, e.g.,  $\alpha!:=\alpha_1!\ldots\alpha_n!$. This is not the case in linear algebra. Actually your problem already arises with harmless matrix elements $a_{ik}$. There one might talk about an *index pair*.